# OO design interview

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I was reading steve yegge's "the 5 essential phone-screen questions" while preparing myself for an interview coming up next week and I ran into this excerpt:

> For example, you may find a candidate who decides that a Vehicle class
>   should be a subclass of ParkingGarage, since garages contain cars.
>   This is just busted, and it's un-fixable in any reasonable amount of
>   training time.

Being rather inexperienced with OO design, I'm trying to understand why this is a broken assumption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to Evan's answer:

When it comes to inheritance, respecting the "is a" (or "is a kind of") relationship isn't the whole story.

A good design will also bear the LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle) in mind.
The principle states that if B is a subtype of A, then A can be replaced with B without any surprising effects. For example, any code that works with a `Vehicle`, would also work with a `Car`.

The classic example that shows how easy it is to break this principle is the Square-Rectangle example.

At first glance, it seems rather obvious to make Square inherit from Rectangle. A square "is a kind of" Rectangle. It's a rectangle, whose width and height are always the same value.
In order to keep this property, you'd probably design your Square class like this:

```
public class Square : Rectangle
{    
  //SetWidth method inherited from Rectangle
  public override void SetWidth(int width) {
    base.width = width;
    base.height = width;
  }
}
```

Perfect. But now, picture the following code:

```
public void SomeMethod(Rectangle rect) {
  rect.SetHeight(10);
  rect.SetWidth(20);
  print(rect.GetHeight());
}
```

This code would expect the third line to print 10, because it just set the rectangle's height to 10. However, if replaced with a Square, it would print 20 instead, causing unexpected behavior - and breaking the Liskov Substitution Principle. So we see that a rectangle cannot always be replaced with a square.

The LSP is one of the five SOLID principles - I recommend reading more about the other 4.

If you're looking for a good OO book, I must say that Head First Design Patterns is a hell of a book, the best I've ever read.
It's slightly related to java, but only slightly, they use it for code samples and nothing else. It's supposed to be language-agnostic and you can read it regardless of your programming background.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and this excellent response. Could you just tell me what are the other 4 SOLID principles that you recommend me reading about?

Comment: @user3043746 [S (Single responsibility)](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) [O (Open close)](http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html) [L (Liskov substitution)](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html) [I (Interface segregation)](http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html) [D (Dependency inversion)](http://www.oodesign.com/dependency-inversion-principle.html). These are essential to design a flexible and maintainable application, and a great trick to have up your sleeve during an interview.

Answer (score 4):

Inheritance is an "is a" relationship.

A `Car` is a `Vehicle`.

A `Vehicle` is **not** a `ParkingGarage`.

A `ParkingGarage` may contain many `Vehicles`, but that's composition, not inheritance

Comment: Thank you. Could I perhaps ask some recommendation on good OO related material? I can't seem to find a single book / tutorial that is language agnostic (or particularly, focused on Python)